# How do I check if a letter from user input is in a word

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

```
secret_word = "Decor"
secret_word = secret_word.lower()

guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
guess = guess.lower()

tries = 0
if secret_word == guess:
  tries += 1
  print("Correct! You got it in", tries, "tries!")
else:
  tries += 2
  print("That is incorrect. You have", tries, "tries left.")

  for char in secret_word:
    if char in guess:
      print("Hint: The following letters are in the secret word - ", char)
```

How do I check a letter from the user input is in the secret word

Answer (score 1):

### Check if `guess` exists as a substring

```
if guess in secret_word:
    print(f"found '{guess}' in {secret_word}")
```

### Check if any characters overlap (regardless of order)

```
if any(c in secret_word for c in guess):
    print(f"found letter from '{guess}' in {secret_word}")
```

### Check if all characters exist (regardless of order)

```
if all(c in secret_word for c in guess):
    print(f"found all letters from '{guess}' within {secret_word}")
```

### Limit your inputs to letters

```
guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
guess = guess.lower()
if len(guess) > 1:
    raise ValueError('input a letter')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no loop, so you only get one try, no matter what. Due to that I had to made the assumption that you are basing this all on tries. With that assumption I fleshed your example out to a MRE. The answer you asked for is commented in the code,.

```
MAXTRIES = 3

secret_word = "decor"
tries = 0

output = ("Correct! you got it in %i tries!",
          "That is incorrect. You have %i tries left.")

while tries<MAXTRIES:
    tries += 1
    
    guess = input("Enter your guess: ").lower()
    wrong = secret_word != guess
    
    print(output[wrong] % abs(MAXTRIES*wrong-tries))

    if wrong:
        #this line is the actual answer to your question
        #you should get all of the characters before you print them
        chars = [char for char in secret_word if char in guess]

        print("Hint: The following letters are in the secret word - ", chars)
```